# Django TypeError in render() call once uploaded to server

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I have a website I'm updating to the latest Django, a point release at a time. Right now I'm on Django 1.9.13 and Python 2.7.5, and I have code that works fine with `manage.py runserver` on my local dev machine, but when I run it to my web host (WebFaction), it fails with this error:

> TypeError at /
>   **init**() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Here's the traceback:

```
File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/optical_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/optical_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/myuser/webapps/optical_test/cinedex/theoptical/views.py" in frontpage
  38.     return render(request, 'theoptical/frontpage.html', context)

File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/optical_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)

File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/optical_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  96.             template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/optical_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  32.                 return engine.get_template(template_name, dirs)

File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/optical_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in get_template
  40.             return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name, dirs), self)

File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/optical_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in get_template
  190.         template, origin = self.find_template(template_name, dirs)

File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/optical_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in find_template
  153.         for loader in self.template_loaders:

File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/optical_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  33.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/optical_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in template_loaders
  118.         return self.get_template_loaders(self.loaders)

File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/optical_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in get_template_loaders
  123.             loader = self.find_template_loader(template_loader)

File "/home/myuser/.virtualenvs/optical_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in find_template_loader
  146.             return loader_class(*args)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Here's `cinedex/theoptical/views.py` in `frontpage`:

```
def frontpage(request):
    context = {'title':"The Optical Test New Front Page"}

    # Don't return episodes with a pubdate in the future
    now = timezone.now()
    if Episode.objects.filter(pubDate__lt=now):
        latest_episode = get_object_or_404(Episode.objects.filter(pubDate__lt=now).order_by('-pubDate')[:1])
        context.update({'latest_episode': latest_episode})

    context.update(masterlinks())
    return render(request, 'theoptical/frontpage.html', context)
```

Have a suggestion where I should look for the bug? Let me know if it would be useful for me to provide more info. Thanks!

**Update**

Here is the TEMPLATES setting from my `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.cached.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ],
            'debug':True,
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Can it be this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/upgrading/ ?

Comment: Check if you are running the same versions of Python and Django on both development and production servers.

Comment: Selcuk, you know what — I am not. I thought I was, but the dev virtualenv is on python 2.7.10.

Comment: Igonato, I don't think so. I've been over that page a few times, and it seems like my template settings are okay. I'll update the question with my TEMPLATES settings, just in case.

Comment: Did you get the traceback from django's debug? What's in `loader_class` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your templates settings seems like `django.template.loaders.cached.Loader` should be set differently ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader)):

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    # ...
    'OPTIONS': {
        'loaders': [
            ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ]),
        ],
    },
}]
```

Comment: That was totally it. Site loads now. Whew! Thank you. Looks like it didn't affect things on the dev `runserver` because caching is disabled by default there.

Comment: @bobtiki exactly. Btw it's auto added when DEBUG = False in 1.11, so you can remove loaders from your settings entirely

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that once I get to 1.11. :D

Answer (score -2):

Your error is occurring from this line

```
latest_episode = get_object_or_404(Episode.objects.filter(pubDate__lt=now).order_by('-pubDate')[:1])
```

You're missing one argument - see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404). You should be doing something like:

```
eps = get_object_or_404(Episode, pubDate__lt=now)
latest_episode = eps.order_by('-pubDate')
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is incorrect, the way OP has it is fine